# Generation of Binary number from some distribution function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

In mathematica, `RandomInteger[]` generates binary numbers (0 or 1) with equal probablity (uniform distribution).

If I wish to generate the binary numbers with unequal probability or from some probability distribution, let's say `Binomial` distribution, then how to generate them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, for 10 binomial numbers of length 5, you could use either [`BinomialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinomialDistribution.html) (as shown by @Kuba in the comments) or [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html)

```
p = 1/10;

SeedRandom[0]

RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, p], {10, 5}]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)

SeedRandom[0]

RandomChoice[{1 - p, p} -> {0, 1}, {10, 5}]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

The approaches are equivalent

```
% == %%%

(* True *)
```